# Orgmode: Priorities on list's items

Tags: org-mode

Is it possible to add priority to items of a list using `orgmode`?

Something like:

```
- [#A] first
- [#A] also imporstant
- [#B] important but a bit less
```

If possible, What about lists with check boxes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not possible, at least not without rewriting a lot of org-mode.  Plain list are just text.  They do not have priorities, tags, properties or any of the other things headlines can have.  If you need priorities, just convert them to headlines with `C-c *` first.

Comment: thank you for the quick response, and the convertion trick!