# Link to item in org document

Tags: org-mode, todo

I have nested headings with lists on them. I want to create a list outside of all those headings that "links" or references items in the other lists, such that changes on them, will affect the ones in the original place. For example, let's say I have some todo lists with checkboxes, organized by topic:

```
* Personal Things
** Some stuff
   - [ ] feed the dog
   - [ ] water the plants
   - [ ] drink water
* Work
  - [ ] say yes sir to my boss
  - [ ] pretend I do something
  - [ ] cramp everything for the last day
* Personal
** Could do
*** Fun
    - [ ] learn org-mode
    - [ ] realize I don't know enough
*** Not fun
    - [ ] Visit mother in law
** Must do
   - [ ] Do the laundry
```

In the same document, below all of that, I want to create a list with my "today's things to do". I want these items to somehow be linked to the ones above, so any change on these ones, will be applied to the originals. (Such as checking the boxes [x] or editing the text.)

I could kill and yank, use, then kill and yank back, but then it is a lot of maintenance + remembering where each thing goes.

```
* Today:
  - [ ] feed the dog
  - [ ] say yes sir to my boss
  - [ ] Do the laundry
```

Is there a way to get this on emacs org-mode? I don't even know how to search for it online. I have tried "references", "links", but that gives me other kind of results. I found out about **sparce trees** too, but don't seem to fit my need. anyway the view is cluttered.

Somebody is asking something similar just today:

- [List all prioritized items in sublistings](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/69124/list-all-prioritized-items-in-sublistings)

Edit 1:

- This is discouraging, It looks like lists are close to just plain text. They don't have tags, priorities, or anything. [Orgmode: Priorities on list's items](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17685/orgmode-priorities-on-lists-items)

Thanks

Comment: "Today's things to do" tells me you want to use the agenda (`C-h i g(org)Agenda Views`), although you'll have to reorganize things in your file(s) to indicate when they are supposed to be done. How is Org mode to figure it out otherwise?

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I was thinking on adding tags to the "today's things". My approach seems to be all wrong, though. How can I get started with org-mode agenda? (I know I can google, but just asking for a nice/brief resource you may know). So far, all I know about org-mode is headings, lists, checkboxes, #+begin_src

Comment: See the "TODO Items" chapter in the manual (`C-h i g(org)TODO items` will get you there). Also, search for "Org mode tutorials" using your favorite web search egine. Or you can start with https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/index.html which lists a bunch of tutorials. The most basic rule is: start small and do not try to learn too many things at once.

Comment: I found this beauty that is getting me started in just 42 pages: https://orgmode.org/orgguide.pdf